# Haversine vs Equirectangular approximation

Tags: distance, haversine

So, I need to calculate distances betweeen two points (lat-lon pairs). I've read about Haversine formula and Equirectangular approximation in [Movable Type Scripts](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Since I only want to calculate short distances (less than 4 KM), is the Equirectangular formula a good approximation?

Also, I've read about lat-lon storage in MySQL databases [in Google Developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1) and they implement the Haversine formula like this:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

My last question is, is there any big performance differences between filtering the points in the sql query (as in the example) and filtering them by code?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested haversine v equirectangular over much larger distances (1000km, within the UK), the difference was on the order of 0.1%. So for distances of 4km or less you might as well use equirectangular for speed unless you have a need for maximum accuracy.